# TypeError at /project/create 'Account' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem. I can not assign user with project using many to many field
here is the details

here is my model.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from workingSkills.models import Domain,Environment,ToolsAndTechnology

class Project(models.Model):
    profile_of = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(Domain)
    environment = models.ManyToManyField(Environment)
    tools_and_technology = models.ManyToManyField(ToolsAndTechnology)
```

here is views.py

```
@login_required(login_url= 'login')
def createProject(request):
    form = createProjectForm()
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = createProjectForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = Account.objects.filter(request.user)
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            #instance.save()
      
            instance.profile_of.set(user)
            instance.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect('createprofile')
    form = createProjectForm
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'project/create_project.html', context)
```

here is error image[image]

Answer (score 0):

change this like this you have to specify for which column you want to filter

```
from:
Account.objects.filter(request.user)
to:
Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

You have made a typo mistake in that query set

Change of queryset  'set' To 'add' in the line

Comment: Thanks... I have now passed the filter step. But getting error here   instance.profile_of.set(user)

Comment: Update your questions screenshot then

Comment: I add some changes to my original answer let me know olif that works or not